# How to determine BananaPi M3 UART specifications

Tags: serial-port, pyserial, uart, banana-pi

I have a [BananaPi M3](http://www.bananapi.org/) device and I am trying to read from UART port some data coming with 4Mb baudrate. I have a harware connected to the UART that generated data with 4Mb baudrate. I made a short script in Python to read the data, but if I set up 4Mb as baudrate I don;t get anything, not even scrambled information. On lower baudrates like 115200 I get scrambled data.

The question is, how to determine what is the maximum baudrate that BananaPi supports on UART port OR how to increate it to support 4Mb baudrate?
Thank you

Comment: This doesn't give you the answer you're looking for, but here is a reference that you might find useful: http://superuser.com/questions/488449/is-there-any-way-to-check-which-baud-rates-are-supported-on-a-serial-device

Comment: Also, I would suggest getting everything working at 115200 before ramping up the data rates. If you're not getting any data, it sounds like the UART, expecting characters as 4 Mbit/sec, is possibly not finding valid start and stop bits, which you might see if the baud rates were off by an order of magnitude. The oversampling on the receive may never see valid bits at 4 Mb/sec.

Comment: You can try to change the baudrate in BananaPi. http://forum.banana-pi.org/t/bpi-m1-uart-only-works-with-baud-rates-of-9600-and-115200-but-not-higher-speeds/1431